# Sum the last two numbers in a filtered column in Excel

Tags: excel, function, sum

I am trying to get the sum of the last two numbers in each row of a filtered column. The rows will range from 2-200 and won't be in order since they will be filtered.

Data is pasted into excel that contains numbers and words. This data is then filtered to get rows that only contain that word and a number value at the end of the row. This data is always going to be in column A. I would only ever need the last 2 numbers of each row and I need these numbers added together to get the total value.

For example.

Column A will display the following:

```
A
28: Filtered word 5466451981-3516415  00:12
30: Filtered word 66413511516 - sfdhsdjfhk 00:08
45: Filtered Word 793734jkdsfhkjhs - jshfjs 00:30
102 Filtered Word fjhlakdjfjsdf - 32342kj323 00:10
```

I'm having a heck of a time funding a function to add the numbers together. In this case with only using those 4 rows (28, 30, 45, 102) the sum I would be looking for is 60. I can use the RIGHT function and add each row together (RIGHT(A28,2)+RIGHT(A30,2)+RIGHT(A45,2)+RIGHT(A102,2)) but I would have to type this in manually and I don't always know how many rows will be in column A (It can be anything from 1 to 200).

Answer (score 1):

If you create a helper column to extract the last 2 digits, then at the bottom you can place the following formula:

```
=SUBTOTAL(109 ,range)
```

Then when you filter your list based on whatever criteria you'd like, the formula offered will only provide the sum of the visible cells. This should accomplish your needs if I understood correctly. Cheers

Comment: using `=right(A2,2)` will get you the last 2 but as text, using: `=NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))` will get you it as a number, so you can sum it.

Comment: that subtotal is a nice function, I've not seen it before. But this is a great use!  :D